# Is it possible to call a mixin from an event onclick in pug?

Tags: javascript, pug

I have the next mixin as example

```
//- Declaration
mixin article(title='Default Title')
  .article
    .article-wrapper
      h1= title
```

I want to call `+article('Hello world')` from a link like this:

```
a(href="#" onclick=`article('Hello world)`) mylink
```

but this isn't working for me.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Pugjs is a rendering engine, which generates HTML. Client side javascript events could in no way trigger mixins or anything in a pug file.